# Fast way to convert to a huge list of floats to a list of strings

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a very large list of floats which I need to convert to a list of strings.  I am looking for a fast way doing this. The naive method takes too much time. What would be the best way to do this.

Comment: `The naive method takes too much time`. What do you consider a naive method?

Comment: how do you plan to use the result list?

Comment: I plan to dump the result list to a text file (in a specific format)

Comment: string conversion will be negligible against io operation

Answer (score 2):

```
import time
def main():
    d = [1.0]*10**7
    st = time.time()
    e = map(str, d)
    print time.time() - st

>>> main()
3.4690001010
```

too much? If not building list:

```
from itertools import imap
def main():
     d = [1.0]*10**7
     id = iter(d)
     st = time.time()
     e = imap(str,id)
     for l in e:
         pass
     print time.time() - st

>>> main()
1.38447939781
```

Comment: It is too much if you have 10**10 numbers!

Comment: If you have 10 billion numbers, you're probably not holding them all in RAM simultaneously, are you? If so, why do you need to stringify them all at once?

Comment: you could use `timeit.default_timer` instead of `time.time` to provide a better precision in a portable way.

Comment: the 2nd code example doesn't create a list. You could write it as `deque(imap(str, d), maxlen=0)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the map function. The map function applies a function to every member of the list and returns a new list.

```
list_Of_Floats = [4.32, 5.12, 5.623]

list_Of_String_Floats = map(str, list_Of_Floats)

print list_Of_String_Floats

# same thing with a comprehension 
list_Of_String_Floats = [str(x) for x in list_Of_Floats]
```

output:
`['4.32', '5.12', '5.623']`

Comment: list comprehension would be even faster, however, it is still slow :(. I have 10**10 floating numbers.

Comment: `lambda` is redundant redundant here. Please, use `pep8`-compatible names e.g., `list_of_strings = map(str, list_of_floats)`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions @J.F.Sebastian. Could you explain what you mean by the lambda being redundant ?

Comment: @jramirez, `str()` is itself a function taking one argument, so `lambda x: str(x)` does the same thing as plain `str`, only slower ;-)  That is, `map(str, list_of_floats)` is better.